# Android kotlin ViewBinding kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

So I want to access a view in a fragment from another fragment. Here I use viewBinding in both fragment. This is what the layout looks like where the View I want to access from other fragment is :

**fragment_dashboard.xml**

```
  <layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/content"/>

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
                android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                app:itemBackground="@color/buttonColor"
                app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
                app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/buyItemButtonColor"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />


    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</layout>
```

This is what `fragment_dashboard.xml`'s Fragment snippet code :

**DashboardFragment.kt**

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

lateinit var binding: FragmentDashboardBinding
var currentSelectedMenu by Delegates.notNull<Int>()

lateinit var username: String
lateinit var memberId: String

private val onNavigateItemListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{ item ->
    ...
}


private fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    fragmentManager
        ?.beginTransaction()
        ?.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.design_bottom_sheet_slide_in, R.anim.design_bottom_sheet_slide_out)
        ?.replace(R.id.content, fragment, fragment.javaClass.simpleName)
        ?.commit()
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false
    )

    val args = arguments?.let {
        DashboardFragmentArgs.fromBundle(
            it
        )
    }


    if (args != null) {
        binding.navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }

    binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigateItemListener)

    val fragment = HomeFragment.newInstance(memberId, username)
    addFragment(fragment)

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return binding.root
}


fun openNavDrawer(){
    binding.drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
}
```

The function `openNavDrawer()` will be executed from another fragment (`HomeFragment.kt`). Here's the snippet code from `HomeFragment.kt`

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

    ...

    binding.navigationDrawerTrigger.setOnClickListener {
        DashboardFragment().openNavDrawer()
    }

}
```

But when executed, it returned :

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized
    at something.dashboard.DashboardFragment.openNavDrawer(DashboardFragment.kt:154)
    at com.example.bottomnavigationexample.HomeFragment$onCreateView$1.onClick(HomeFragment.kt:83)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6719)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6677)
    at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:797)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26475)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7212)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:956)
```

Did I miss something ? Or maybe the variable `binding` from in the `DashboardFragment.kt` should moved elsewhere ? If there's any detail I miss to point out, just let me know !

Comment: please try this inside onCreateView() for the HomeFragment.kt

binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater)

//add this as the return value for the onCreateView() method
return binding.root

Comment: Sorry @Fanadez , still not working. The problem is in the `DashboardFragment.kt ` I think

Comment: yeah the problem seems to be on DashboardFragment. Try cleaning and rebuilding the projects and make sure there are no errors on the xml files and databinding is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

- Caused

When You click in `HomeFragment` with `DashboardFragment().openNavDrawer()`,

```
binding.navigationDrawerTrigger.setOnClickListener {
        DashboardFragment().openNavDrawer()
    }
```

it means you call `openNavDrawer()` with a `new fragment instance` of `DashboardFragment`,  (the new one)

not `the original fragment`.  (the original one)

---

- Why

> it has not been initialized?

Because it (the new one) did not managed by your FragmentManager and show on screen so that will not do createView()

(although you should not do this with DashboardFragment())

---

- What Should you do

You should use `the original dashboard fragment` to do what you want to do.

Such as:

1. Pass `dashboard reference` into `home`
2. find the `dashboard fragment` by your fragmentManager in `home`

then `home` can interact with `dashboard`

```
binding.navigationDrawerTrigger.setOnClickListener {
        the_origin_dashboard_fragment.openNavDrawer()
    }
```